# How do I release the ACTUAL memory and not just the pointer to the memory?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management

I am releasing things but the memory seems to still be there according to instruments. Am I just releasing the pointer and not the actual data? How do I release THE DATA in objective-c? What's the difference between `[anObject release]` or `[&anObject release]`?

Please excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject of memory and pointers.

Comment: I don't think "[&anObject release];" is even valid Objective-C. Assuming "anObject" has a type of "NSObject *" or "id", that would mean "&anObject" would be a pointer to a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[anObject release];
```

Specifically, you are telling the object to decrement its retain count by 1.   If it happens to fall to zero -- which it might not for a variety of reasons -- then the Objective-C runtime will invoke the method `-dealloc` which will then invoke `-release` on all of the object type instance variables (and `free()` on malloc'd memory, if any).

There is no magic here.  `release` is just a method call like any other method call.   Given the question, I would suggest you read this:

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

And, once you have dispelled the mysticism of calling methods, read this to fully understand memory management on the iPhone:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: Cool -- do so.  The conceptual guides truly are an awesome place to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
[anObject release];
```

Tells the object to decrement its `retain` count by 1. Every time you `alloc` or `copy` an object, you are returned an object with a retain count of one. Then, if you `retain` it again, the count increments. Or if you use a retain property, again, it goes up.

Calling release, like I said, decrements this count. When the count reaches zero, the object gets sent `dealloc` which (through calls to `[super dealloc]`) will eventually deallocate all the memory used for that object.

There's also `autorelease`, but I'll leave that for you to discover. You should read the [Memory Management docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Study them well.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, memory allocators don't return memory to the operating system immediately after release (or even ever). Thus, if the instrumentation you're looking at uses OS-level statistics, it won't see usage go down even after you've released some dynamically allocated object.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I am using the Leaks Instrument of the iPhone SDK and usually I can see graphs of object allocations (living objects) fall immediately, but in this case its different... What does calling [&anObject release] do BTW?

Comment: I don't know. I've never written a line of Objective-C in my life.